# Copying gzip file to Vertica using python

Tags: python-2.7, copy, vertica

I am trying to copy gzip file to Vertica in my python script. Below is my code

```
import vertica_python
conn_info = {******}
connection = vertica_python.connect(**conn_info)
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS home01")
cur.execute( "CREATE TABLE home01( ....;")

cur.copy("copy home01(path, directories, files, reported_bytes, actual_bytes, path_level) from local '/work/directory.home01.out.gz' GZIP ;")
```

I get this error when I run the script

[root@#######]# ./pyvertica.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./pyvertica.py", line 16, in <module> cur.copy("copyhome01(path, directories, files, reported_bytes, actual_bytes, path_level) from local '/work/directory.home01.out.gz' GZIP ;")

TypeError: copy() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

I can copy the same file if its decompressed, but with the compressed mode I cannot. https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/BulkLoadCOPY/UsingCOPYAndCOPYLocal.htm

Comment: Are you sure you can copy the same file if it's decompressed with the same command? (without GZIP of course)

Comment: Try giving delimiter also .

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `COPY LOCAL` with `vertica_python`.  The most similar method would be to use `COPY FROM STDIN`, which is what `copy()` is really about.

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('/work/directory.home01.out.gz','r') as inf:
    cur.copy("copy home01(path, directories, files, reported_bytes, actual_bytes, path_level) from STDIN", inf)
```

If you want to do a standard `COPY` (from a node) then you'd just use `execute()` like any other query. `copy()` is specifically designed for `COPY FROM STDIN`.